# (obj || {}) vs Object(obj)

Tags: javascript

Are there any important differences (semantical, performance-related, etc.) between (1) and (2)?

1. `var obj = obj || {};`
2. `var obj = Object(obj);`

*Context.* The first is the way I've been sharing variables across Django's templates and my js files. I just came across a section in Rauschmayer 2014 ("Functions for Converting Boolean, Number, String, and Object", pg. 79), where he described `Object(obj)` as follows:

- `obj` if `obj` is an object,
- `{}` if `obj` is `undefined` or `null`,
- [wrapped primitive] if `obj` is a primitive value.

Given that (very informal) semantics (particularly the first two clauses), it seems to me that we can use (2) wherever we would use (1), but I'm not entirely sure what consequences this will have.

<sub>Rauschmayer, Axel (2014) [Speaking JavaScript](http://speakingjs.com/) (free to read online).</sub>

Comment: `1` is a common idiom, `2` is not. To make your code understandable to most programmers, stick with the usual syntax.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes there is a difference, as the quote you gave already mentions. The first notation will return the primitive itself when `obj` was a primitive. The second one will return a *wrapped* primitive, which is an object.

If the rest of the code relies on `obj` being an object, the second notation is more defensive.

But then again, the first notation is more common, and one might wonder how a primitive value would be assigned to a variable named `obj` anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful response. Very helpful.